# I am not able to see background image of div in print preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this html There is div which contains a background image. and inside it there is a mark img. working good on browser but at the time of print background image not coming still mark is coming

```
<div id="picx" style="background:url(img/large_eyeball.png);">
<img id="picx" src="img/cross.png">
</div>
```

I have also checked option of background color and image option in print preview settings. Please explain me what is going wrong.

I am using Google chrome. following function to print page.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    window.print();

}
</script>
```

Comment: Background images are not printed by default. If you have changed settings so that they should be printed and this does not work, then this is a problem with the browser or with the printer software, not a programming issue. Consider asking at SuperUser *with sufficient information provided* (including exact identification of the browser and the setting set).

Answer (score -2):

Try background-image instead of background

```
<div id="picx" style="background-image:url(img/large_eyeball.png);">
<img id="picx" src="img/cross.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Oops! not getting right output. I have check it on chrome